# How To Change Font Color on Mobile Res

Tags: html, jquery, css, saas

I'm having hard time trying to fix this small issue with my website, so the body text shows in white on the desktop, which is good, but when I use the smaller devices I don't want the text to show white because it collapse with the white background and you can't read the text. How can I change it to another color for mobile versions, with CSS, or HTML?

[This Is How It Shows On Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpaA5.png)

[This Is How It Shows On Smaller Screens (Phones, Tablets, etc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR8nK.png)

Edits from Stackoverflow (that didn't work)

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .mob1 {
     color: #ffffff;
   }
  }
  
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .mob1 {
     color: #000000;
   }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<p style="color: aliceblue;" class="custom-article wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".2s"><span class="mob1">Changed Text</span></p>
```

- I tried to add the mob1 to the p class, didn't worked either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use media queries.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

For more details: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: So, i want to change text color, not bg color. (Also can I add class??)

Comment: it was just sample code. You can add your custom class and css property.
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .my-text {
    color: lightblue;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

try this

on the html file, if it is a p element, or whatever type of text element it is,

```
<p class="colourTest">TEXT</p>

in the css file: 

//for screens smaller then mobile
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .colourTest {
   text-color: black;
}
}

//for screens bigger then mobile
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .colourTest {
   text-color: white;
}
}
```

Comment: `text-color` in CSS is actually just `color`

Comment: @tacoshy It doesn't work, I tried without text-color. Nothing happens.

Comment: @user14518181 you cannot specify the colour in the p style, it will override the css. take that out, and put the class"mob1" like this, <p class="mob1">